# Path for Weblogic Home& Java home for adding Oracle server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, weblogic, settings, java-home

I had installed oracle weblogic tool for in my eclipse luna by simple drag and drop to my workspace from [eclipse-marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/oracle-weblogic-server-tools-luna)..tool appers when i am going to add a new server in eclipse but Can anyone please tell what to put in 
Weblogic home and javaHome here [image]
.............................**Do i have to download oacler weblogic server ??????** Tool for oracle server is already there in eclipse. i also crosschecked my computer there is no any weblogic server folder anywhere....??Please Help Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes, you have to download weblogic server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes We have to download the Oracle Weblogic Server from Following path:
1st -- go to http://www.oracle.com/index.html
2nd---then from top menu select downloads...go to Middleware...Expand the + sign of See All The Middleware Downloads..
Then expand all previous and current version of weblogic server from WebLogic Server 12c and WebLogic Server 11g Releases.
From there select WebLogic Server 12c (any New version you want)..then download according to your window configuration. Run that .exe file while run it will ask for path where you want to place this Middleware folder.Now give that path while sever configuraton in eclipse.
[image: .]
Please go through this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IVyX0jyrVA) video if you have still questions..